# What's the most elegant way to use > and < operands when variables can be Nonetype in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python3 using a `>` or `<` operand on a `NoneType` will result in a TypeError.

E.g. when comparing two dates, I can use:

```
a = datetime(...)
b = datetime(...)

if a < b:
   // do something
```

But if `a = None` for some reason (e.g. it's the result of a function), then this results in:

```
'<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'DateTime'
```

In python2 this would evaluate to `True`.

If `a` and `b` are variables and can be a `datetime` or `None`, **and I want to skip the comparison if either value is `None`,** what's the most elegant way to solve for this?

E.g. the following works, but it feels like there's a better one-line approach?

```
if a and b:
   if a < b:
       // do something
```

Comment: `if a is not None and b is not None:`

Comment: Well what do you want to happen if one or the other *is* None? Your examples don't do anything, can you give some context?

Comment: a < b if a is not None and b is not None else (whatever your default is)

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve. Do you think that a comparison to None makes sense? If so, just define your own comparison function or use operator overloading.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, clarified with more explicit examples

Comment: I'm still not sure that addresses the question that @jonrsharpe raised. How do you want the program to behave depending on whether the values are `None` ?

Comment: @AMC, if either of the values are `None` I want it to skip the comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using objects and not numbers here, I'd go with the short and explicit:

```
if (a and b) and (a < b):
    # Do something
```

If either `a` or `b` are `None`, it will short-circuit and the comparison is never executed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `or` operator:

```
a = None
b = 1    
int(a or 0) < b
```

Output:

```
True
```

`int(a or 0)` returns `0` if `a` is `None`, otherwise, it will return `a` *(if `a` is a number)*.

---

#### UPDATE: To address the updated question:

```
if None not in [a,b]: # if neither values are None
    # Do something
```

Comment: @AMC You should check the edit history of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an extended if statement, but I typically prefer to use a `try` block. This ends up being very readable, and explicitly handles `TypeErrors` while also providing a relatively convienient way to handle other errors that may come down the pipe.

```python3
try:
  if a < b:
    do_the_thing()
except TypeError:
  handle_bad_types()
```

Comment: _This ends up being very readable_ Isn't it less explicit/clear in its intention than just checking for `None`, though?

Comment: Possibly. Though if we're worried about our incoming typing this offers much broader protection than the other option. Adding a comment as to why this would put in place wouldn't be amiss.

Comment: That's true, there's definitely an upside.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import datetime

# a, b can be datetime objects, or None
a = datetime.datetime.now()
b = None

if a is not None and b is not None:
    print("Neither values are None, do your operation here.")
else:
    print("One or both the values are None, operation was not performed.")
```